# Kryo serialization error in Spark job

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, kryo

I want to use Kryo serialization in Spark job.

```
public class SerializeTest {

    public static class Toto implements Serializable {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 6369241181075151871L;
        private String a;

        public String getA() {
            return a;
        }

        public void setA(String a) {
            this.a = a;
        }
    }

    private static final PairFunction<Toto, Toto, Integer> WRITABLE_CONVERTOR = new PairFunction<Toto, Toto, Integer>() {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = -7119334882912691587L;

        @Override
        public Tuple2<Toto, Integer> call(Toto input) throws Exception {
            return new Tuple2<Toto, Integer>(input, 1);
        }
    };

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SparkConf conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("SerializeTest");
        conf.set("spark.serializer", "org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer");
        conf.registerKryoClasses(new Class<?>[]{Toto[].class});
        JavaSparkContext context = new JavaSparkContext(conf);

        List<Toto> list = new ArrayList<Toto>();
        list.add(new Toto());
        JavaRDD<Toto> cursor = context.parallelize(list, list.size());

        JavaPairRDD<Toto, Integer> writable = cursor.mapToPair(WRITABLE_CONVERTOR);
        writable.saveAsHadoopFile(args[0], Toto.class, Integer.class, SequenceFileOutputFormat.class);

        context.close();
    }

}
```

But i have this error :

> java.io.IOException: Could not find a serializer for the Key class: 'com.test.SerializeTest.Toto'. Please ensure that the configuration 'io.serializations' is properly configured, if you're usingcustom serialization.
>               at org.apache.hadoop.io.SequenceFile$Writer.init(SequenceFile.java:1179)
>               at org.apache.hadoop.io.SequenceFile$Writer.(SequenceFile.java:1094)
>               at org.apache.hadoop.io.SequenceFile.createWriter(SequenceFile.java:273)
>               at org.apache.hadoop.io.SequenceFile.createWriter(SequenceFile.java:530)
>               at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.SequenceFileOutputFormat.getRecordWriter(SequenceFileOutputFormat.java:63)
>               at org.apache.spark.SparkHadoopWriter.open(SparkHadoopWriter.scala:90)
>               at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$13.apply(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1068)
>               at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$13.apply(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1059)
>               at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:61)
>               at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:64)
>               at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:203)
>               at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>               at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>               at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
>       15/09/21 17:49:14 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0, localhost): java.io.IOException: Could not find a serializer for the Key class: 'com.test.SerializeTest.Toto'. Please ensure that the configuration 'io.serializations' is properly configured, if you're usingcustom serialization.
>               at org.apache.hadoop.io.SequenceFile$Writer.init(SequenceFile.java:1179)
>               at org.apache.hadoop.io.SequenceFile$Writer.(SequenceFile.java:1094)
>               at org.apache.hadoop.io.SequenceFile.createWriter(SequenceFile.java:273)
>               at org.apache.hadoop.io.SequenceFile.createWriter(SequenceFile.java:530)
>               at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.SequenceFileOutputFormat.getRecordWriter(SequenceFileOutputFormat.java:63)
>               at org.apache.spark.SparkHadoopWriter.open(SparkHadoopWriter.scala:90)
>               at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$13.apply(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1068)
>               at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$13.apply(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1059)
>               at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:61)
>               at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:64)
>               at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:203)
>               at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>               at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>               at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error is related neither to *Spark* nor *Kryo*.

When using *Hadoop output formats* you need to make sure your *key* and *value* are instances of `Writable`. Hadoop doesn't use Java serialization by default (and you don't want to use it either, because it's very ineffective)

You can check your `io.serializations` property in configuration and you'll see list of used serializers including `org.apache.hadoop.io.serializer.WritableSerialization`

To fix this issue your `Toto` class must implement `Writable`. The same issue is with `Integer`, use rather `IntWritable`.

Comment: Ok, it works. There is no way to do this by just implementing `java.io.Serializable` and adding an other serializer in `io.serializations` conf? With Kryo we can do this `new Kryo().writeClassAndObject(output, someSerializableObject)`.

Comment: You can add `org.apache.hadoop.io.serializer.JavaSerialization` class to `io.serializations`. It should work then with Java serialization, but I wouldn't recommend this. It'll be slower.